# Japanese content on english page?

Tags: language

A client's site is english and he wants to have one page where the header & footer remain in english but the page content(text & links) is Japanese. I'm wondering what the best practices for this are and what kind of gotchas might come up.

Comment: this looks like a trivial question. can you provide some image what you need?

Answer (score 0):

use wpml plugin and change page or post content. https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpml-to-multilingualpress/